# How to have array on click stay at index[0]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make an array `onclick` go down an index. However, every time I get to 0, it goes to the highest indexed element. I tried to make `"X"` item *go down*, but it doesn't seem to work.

The *go down* mean as an `[0, 1, 2, "X", 4]`, when clicked the new array would look like `[0, 1, "X", 3, 4]`. However, when `"X"` is at index 0 i.e `["X", 1, 2, 3, 4]` the item's position of the array should not change upon clicking

```js
// array
let player1gameboard2 = ["X", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

function changePositionPlayer1Down(player1gameboard2) {
  // prints out array
  console.log(player1gameboard2)

  document.getElementById("player1_test").innerHTML = player1gameboard2

  // condition if array is less than 1. Normally goes to highest index. should just stay at lowest index
  if (player1gameboard2.indexOf("X") === 0) {
    player1gameboard2.splice(
      //future index of element
      0,
      // original element
      0,

      // how to get original element
      // [0] means it is an array
      // means 1 element
      player1gameboard2.splice(0, 1)[0]
    )
    // prints out new array
    document.getElementById("player1_test").innerHTML = player1gameboard2
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Array printed out on screen -->
<p id="player1_test"></p>

<!-- every time button clicked, indexed array goes down one space -->
<button onclick="changePositionPlayer1Down(player1gameboard2)">Go Down</button>
```

Comment: What is really mean of "go down" ?

Comment: [0, 1, 2, "X", 4] when clicked the new array would look like: [0, 1, "X", 3, 4]. However, when "X" is at index 0 ie: ["X", 1, 2, 3, 4] X then appears at the end of the array at [0, 1,2 ,3 "X"]

Comment: Instead of the array staying at ["X", 1, 2, 3, 4]. Once the array is at index [0], the array's position should not change upon clicking

Answer (score 1):

The issue almost comes from `if(player1gameboard2.indexOf("X") === 0)`, due to your requirement, it should be `if(player1gameboard2.indexOf("X") !== 0)`

Second, it's on the updated index of elements. The index of *move element* `"X"` will change on every update, not just `0`.

```
const moveElement = "X";
let player1gameboard2 = [0, 1, 2, moveElement, 4, 5, 6]
function changePositionPlayer1Down(arr) {
    console.log(arr)

    const fromIndex = arr.indexOf(moveElement);
    
    if (fromIndex === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // replace "X" at fromIndex - 1
    arr.splice(
        fromIndex - 1,
        0,
        // cut ["X"] out of array and get "X"
        arr.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0] // same and could replace as "X"
    )
    // update value of the number has been shifted
    arr[fromIndex]++;
    document.getElementById("player1_test").innerHTML = player1gameboard2
}
```